# No way to filter by bounty in mobile apps?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounty, android-app, ios-app

Is there a way to filter questions by bounty offered in the iOS (and possibly android) app(s)? I would expect to see something similar to the "featured" tab from the web version of SO.

If not, why isn't this a feature? It seems like it would be a relatively simple way to shine more light on high-priority questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be fixed for iOS in 1.4.4.6, currently in review.

More details are at [Stack Exchange iOS app is getting new question nav](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276115/stack-exchange-ios-app-is-getting-new-question-nav) but you will now be able to save custom question list sorts including bounties on tags.